# Как в обработчике blur дождаться окончания обработки в focus

Tags: jquery, angularjs, blur, focus

Возникла проблема с созданием `datepicker` для поля даты. На поле висит 2 обработчика - `blur` и `focus`, в `focus` создается `datepicker`, в `blur` он удаляется. Причем в `focus` он создается с помощью deferred объекта.

```
.directive('datePicker', [ '$compile', '$document', 'datePickerService', '$templateRequest', function ($compile, $document, datePickerService, $templateRequest) { 
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            var picker = null;
                var $elementFocusProcessing = $.Deferred();
                element.on('focus', function (event) {
                    populatelimits();
                    prepareViewData();
                    var pos = angular.extend(element.offset(), { height: element[0].offsetHeight });                    

                    $templateRequest(datePickerService.datePickerTemplate).then(function (html) {
                        var template = angular.element(html);
                        $document.find('body').append(template);
                        picker = $compile(template)(scope);
                        picker.css({ top: pos.top + pos.height + 5, left: pos.left, display: 'block', position: 'absolute' });

                        picker.on('mousedown', function (evt) {
                            evt.preventDefault();
                        });
                        $elementFocusProcessing.resolve();
                    });
                });

                element.on('blur', function () {
                    $elementFocusProcessing.then(function () {
                        if (picker) {
                            picker.remove();
                            picker = null;
                        };
                        $elementFocusProcessing = $.Deferred();
                    });
                });
            }

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: link,
            scope : {
                model: '=ngModel'
            }
        };
```

И собственно проблема: если выделить поле даты, потом переключиться на другое окно, а затем кликнуть на любое место страницы, кроме поля даты, возникают подряд несколько событий: `focus` поля, `blur` поля, `click` по странице. При этом создание `picker` в `focus` завершается позже, чем попытка его удаления в `blur`, и он не удаляется, хотя фокус элемента в тоге оказывается потерян. Как сделать так, чтобы выполнение кода в `blur` происходило только после завершения выполнения кода в `focus`? Мне пока пришло в голову только сделать дополнительную переменную `focusEnded` для определения того, идет ли выполнение кода в `focus`, а в `blur` организовать цикл с таймаутом, но чувствую, что можно более изящно сделать это с использованием deferred объектов.

Comment: вот тут как раз такой случай, когда надо [привести минимальный рабочий пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) например на plunkr или jsfiddle :-)

Comment: в принципе могу предложить теоретический ответ без проверки, но он может не сработать, или сработать не так :-) кстати, на сколько я понимаю, вы еще и _angularjs_ используете?

Comment: кстати, а зачем каждый раз на _focus_ лезть в _templateRequest_? у вас может поменяться _datePickerService.datePickerTemplate_?

Comment: Grundy, не уверена, что в jsfiddle воспроизведется проблема, потому что даже в приложении проблема только при переключении из неполноэкранного другого приложения. Приведенный код писала не я, template не меняется. Буду рада любому даже теоретическому совету, потому что пытаюсь в focus сделать resolve для созданного deferred объекта, но в blur его свойство isresolved все время undefined.

Comment: так _angular_ все-таки используете? Эта часть кода находится в директиве? добавьте саму директиву тоже, минимальный пример

Comment: Ага, используем) Пожалуй, поделюсь попыткой применения deferred объекта

Comment: Дополнила код. Да, в директиве. Она начинается с     .directive('datePicker', [
        '$compile', '$document', 'datePickerService', '$templateRequest', function ($compile, $document, datePickerService, $templateRequest) {
            function link(scope, element, attrs) {

Comment: код из комментария в пост добавьте

Comment: сразу подсказка - в ангуляре уже есть отличные _promise_ в модуле `$q` лучше использовать их чем из jQuery, тем более их и так возвращают большинство методов в ангуляре

Comment: и где-то `return link` потеряли?

Comment: Ничего от вас не утаишь. Да, добавила в код

Comment: итак, первое - _Promise_ вещь одноразовая, если один раз сказали _resolve_ то на любой следующей проверке он будет resolve

Comment: Спасибо! Я просто еще не разобралась с deferred, теперь понятно. Добавила создание объекта после удаления datepicker в blur ($elementFocusProcessing = $.Deferred()), это помогло. Но обязательно посмотрю про $q, как только deferred в голове уляжется.

Comment: Лучше сразу сейчас смотреть, они работают примерно одинаково

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как рабочего примера нет, можно рассуждать только теоретически:

1. Так как шаблон не меняется, его не нужно подгружать не только на каждый фокус, но и на каждый link. Следовательно, его можно вынести из функции и результат, а он является *promise*, сохранить в переменной:

   ```
   var templatePromise = $templateRequest(datePickerService.datePickerTemplate);
   ```
2. Далее, функция link, внутри нее подразумеваем, что шаблон уже подгрузился, для этого все остальное делаем в обработчике *success* функции *then* у нашего сохраненного `templatePromise`

   ```
   function link(scope,element,attrs){
       templatePromise.then(function(html){
           //достаточно сделать всего один элемент,
           // который мы будем добавлять или удалять
           var template = angular.element(html);

           //и добавим событие, чтобы не добавлять его каждый раз
           //так как template это уже объект jqLite можно сделать так
           template.on('mousedown', 
               function (evt) {
                   evt.preventDefault();
               }
           );

           //добавляем on focus
           element.on('focus', function (event) {
               ...
                $document.find('body').append(template);
                $compile(template)(scope);
                //так как template это объект jqLite, то вместо picker можно использовать его
                template.css(...)
               ...
           });

           //добавляем on blur
           element.on('blur', function () {
               //так как добавляли template, то и удалять можно его
               //а так как он у нас всегда есть, то не надо проверять на null
               template.remove();
           });
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, оптимизирую. Вопрос закрыт.